# Frequency range mobile phone microphone

Tags: mobile, range, frequency

Does anyone know the approximately frequency range of a mobile phone microphone?
I tried to search for it everywhere but couldn't find the answer.
I know the range is different for almost every type of mobile but let's say a mobile from the newer generations like an iPhone 5 or something.

Thanks in advance.